# google contact api PHP

Tags: api, google-contacts-api

I'm, trying to get content of this URL

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=XXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&v=3.0&max_result=500
```

but received error code 401 with description : There was an error in your request. That's all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to point.

A successful Oauth authentication needs to be implemented first before you are able to make a HTTP request. Be sure to use the correct scope that you need; In your case, you're using the read/write scope.

Refer to this [LINK](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started#3-set-up-your-app) as an example on implementing OAuth on PHP.

Second, v and oauth_token are not valid URL parameters for HTTP requests.  Check this [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#contacts-query-parameters-reference) documentation for more information.

Hope this helps.